# Mail Merge with Excel Document stored in SharePoint

Tags: document-library, office-365, email, excel, word

We have an Excel Document we would like to use as a source file for a Mail Merge in Word. When we open the Excel file in the mail merge wizard we receive the following error.

> "Sorry we couldn't find your file. It is possible it was moved,
>   renamed or deleted?"

I've confirmed this same scenario on several Excel documents.

Comment: what is office and sharepoint version?

Comment: Office 365 and Microsoft Office 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this feature is not supported but still you want their is one workaround for this but not supported .doing unsupported things generally equals "trouble", if not immediately, then later, so even if you can actually get this to work

Read the reply from **Peter Jamieson** on [Mail Merge from SharePoint 2013](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/mail-merge-from-sharepoint-2013/9ce26caa-f6e5-4e5c-a44e-5cb0c3b927e5)

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/72921

Comment: Could you summarize the link contents, in case it is moved or deleted in the future? Link-only answers are generally discouraged.

Answer (score -1):

Make another folder name should be as short as possible, Copy from existing folder to new file, and open.

Comment: Would please elaborate your answer with some example so that other visitors will get more help :)